# MEAN STACK: Mongoose model bloqueia a comunicação com meu controller

Tags: node.js, mongoose, model

Meu *controller* não envia os dados pro meu *router* quando meu *Model* está sendo exportado na aplicação e eu não sei porquê isso acontece.

**controller.js**

```
var Model = require('../models/dado.js');

exports.listaDados = function(req, res) {
  Model.find({}, function(erro, lista) {
    if(erro) console.log(erro);
    res.json(lista);
  });
};
```

**dados.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
  nome: {type: String, required: true},
  idade: {type: Number, required: true, index: {unique: false}}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Dado', schema);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "teste",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "ejs": "^2.5.6",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "express-load": "^1.1.15",
    "method-override": "^2.3.9",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.27",
    "mongoose": "^4.10.4"
  }
}
```

**router.js**

```
var controller = require('../controllers/controller');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/dados', controller.listaDados);
};
```

Se eu comentar a parte do codigo que exporta o *Model*, tipo:

```
//module.exports = mongoose.model('Dado', schema);
```

Meu *controller* passa a funcionar de boas, consigo até enviar dados estáticos do *server* para o cliente, porém eu preciso do *Model* pra pegar os dados do banco.

> Obs: Mongoose conecta normal, tudo funciona ok com exceção dessa parte.

Comment: Quando deixa o model não tem nenhum erro no console? Experimentou ao invés de comentar a linha que exporta o model comentar o `Model.find()`? Ao invés de exportar direto o modelo, tente exportar uma função que retorna o modelo, assim: `module.exports = function() { // todo o código dado.js..return mongoose.model('Dado', schema); } `

Answer (score 1):

Pelo código apresentado no link do Gist do github, está faltando o arquivo de configuração do mongoose.

O seu arquivo dado, está faltando fazer o require do seu arquivo de configuração do mongoose.

ex: `var db = require('./meu_arquivo_de_config_do_mongo');`

Ficando algo similar a isto.

```js
var db = require('./meu_arquivo_de_config_do_mongo');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var dadoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // ...
});

module.exports = db.model('Dado',  dadoSchema);
```

Perceba que você cria um novo Schema para adicionar a instância já existente do mongoose. No código anterior você não passa essa instância para ninguém.